# Check selected item in <select>-Roll?

Tags: javascript, dom, select

So, I got a `<select>`-Roll with multiple items. How can I check via DOM which item was selected? I think I'd usually know it but I'm having a big blackout the whole day today...

Comment: What is a `Roll`? Are you just talking about a `<select>` input element?

Comment: Hehe :) I didn't know any better word for that :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript:

```
//Almost any modern browser
document.getElementById("select-element").value;

//for some old browsers
var select = document.getElementById("select-element");
select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
```

html:

```
<select id="select-element">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
<select>
```

Comment: Your welkom. Please accept as excepted answer if it's a good solution.