# Setting HTML select value using JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html-select

**`index.php`**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setActionStar(btnValue) {
 var actionstar = document.getElementById('actionstars');

 alert(btnValue);
 alert(actionstar.value);

 actionstar.value = btnValue;
 return false;
}
</script>

<form> 
 <?php
  $actionstars = array("Jean Claude Van Damme", "Scott Adkins", "Dolph Lundgren", "Michael Jai White");

  $ctr = 1;
 ?>

 <select id="actionstars" name="actionstars">
  <?php
   foreach($actionstars as $as){
    echo "<option value=" . $ctr . " >" . $as . "</option>";
    $ctr++;
   }
  ?>
 </select>

 <br />

 <?php
  for($i=1; $i<= count($actionstars); $i++) {
 ?>
 <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" onclick="setActionStar(this.value);" />
 <?php
  }
 ?>
</form>
```

I've been dealing with this dilemma for almost 2 hours. I don't know what's wrong with this. What I'm trying to do is whenever the user clicks a button, it will change the combobox value to the value of the button. For example, if I hit button 1, the combobox will have the value 1. It's working with other HTML elements but I don't know why it's not applicable here.

I am very new to programming so don't be harsh to me. Please don't think I didn't do an effort on this. It's just I don't know what I am doing honestly. Please help.

Comment: why would you lood to print more than one submit buttons?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204387/check-selected-item-in-select-roll

Comment: @achshar - fairly common requirement, if the buttons have name and value attributes then the name and value of the one that is used to submit the form is sent too so the server can tell which one was used to submit the form.

Comment: @RobG hmm yes that would help identify which button was pressed but is there a use case for this? like when would it be useful in practical life to know if a form was submitted from one button or the other? its kind of rare i guess..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through the options to find the one with the value you want, then set its selected property to true (and set the selected property of any other selected option to false). Or you can set the selectedIndex property of the select element to the index of the appropriate option.

#### Edit - simple example

```
<form>
  <select id="sel0" name="foo">
    <option selected>default
    <option value="a">a
    <option value="b">b
    <option value="c">c
  </select>
  <input type="button" onclick="setSelect('sel0','a')" value="Set to a">
  <input type="button" onclick="setSelect('sel0','b')" value="Set to b">
  <input type="button" onclick="setSelect('sel0','c')" value="Set to c">
  <br>
  <input type="reset">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function setSelect(id, value) {
    var sel = document.getElementById(id);
    var option, options = sel.options;
    var i = options.length;
    while (i--) {
      option = options[i];
      option.selected = (option.value == value)? true : false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

There are more efficient and generic ways of doing it, the above shows the basic approach.

Comment: Can you show that to me pls... I really don't know how to do that. I know its kinda too much to ask but I am bit running out of time... I need to submit this exercise for checking...

Answer (score 3):

Use the `selectedIndex` property of the `select` element to set the selected index:

```
actionstars.selectedIndex = 0;
```

Only instead of setting it to 0, you need to figure out what the right value is from your `btnValue`.

See also here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp

Comment: I did actionstars.selectedIndex = btnValue - 1; What happens is that after I hit the button it goes to the correct index but after half a second it goes back to the default index...

Comment: I'm not sure.  What are you using for the combobox?  Is it just a straight-up HTML select element, or is it enhanced with jQuery?

Comment: Change the input to type button. It is currently a submit button so the form is submitting right after the script finishes.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot set the value of a select like that.. you will need to add 'selected' in the 'option' tag that has to be selected..

**EDIT** i see you requested code.. here it is.. :)

the javascript

```
actionstar.value = function() {
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#actionstars option'), function(col) {
        if(col.value==btnValue) col.selected = true;
        else col.selected = false;
    });    
}
```

BTW i think you need `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`

Answer (score -1):

You can see it as that your select element. Does have Number of options and they have values. So if you are going to set the value of Select element it wont work. You need to set the value of the options element.